Siesta: Is that the advantage of using bulk-like metallic electrodes we can calculate channel materials of arbitrary length?
When we talk about adding extra screening layers to screen charges towards electrodes when we use semiconductors as electrodes,it sounds like the screening layers are not what we expect in our device. For example, I would like my channel length to be 1.5 nm,but to make transiesta work, I have to add extra screening layers in my device,at last,my channel length is 3 nm('expected 1.5 nm channel length'+ '1.5nm screening layer length'). However, using bulk like metallic electrodes, I can expect my channel material with arbitrary length,and when there is problem with screening length,all I need to do is adding electrode material instead of channel materials. Is my understanding correct ?
